# How to launch background cycle from bash-script from Ansible-playbook

Tags: bash, ansible

I'm creating a simple Traffic simulator: a client that curl a Webserver every 10 seconds. The client(Debian) and the WebServer are configured using Ansible. The background-cycle is closed when the Ansible-SSH connection is closed.

At first I launched the command:

```
$ while true; do curl python_webserver:8000; sleep10; done </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &;
$ disown
```

And It works fine from Bash, but if I put it into a script, it exit at ssh-connection end.
I try some other solutions, like using:

```
$ nohup [command]
$ nohup /bin/bash -c '[command]
```

or using "deamonize" but nothing worked. Nothing I found online works; maybe I'm missing something important. (Writing the pid is important, but not fundamental)

I here the script, maybe there is a big newbie error.

```
#!/bin/bash
PORT=8000
while true; do
    curl python_webserver:$PORT
    sleep 10
done >/dev/null 2>&1 &
ANSIBLE_CLIENT_PID=$!
echo $ANSIBLE_CLIENT_PID >> /tmp/ANSIBLE_PID.txt
disown
```

Comment: @oguzismail The script is launched by an Ansible-playbook, so I cannot launch it using setsid().

Comment: So did you try `nohup sh -c 'while true; do curl python_webserver:'"$PORT"'; sleep 10; done >/dev/null 2>&1' &` ?

Comment: Ansible can execute a script or a command on remote host using SSH connection, so I can execute  setsid if installed on remote host.[https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/script_module.html].
I tried launching it as a command or inside the script, but the background process still exit on ssh-connection end.

Comment: @KamilCuk It works! Probably I made some mistake with quotation marks! Thank you so so so so much

Answer (score 0):

The answers is

```
nohup sh -c 'while true; do curl python_webserver:'"$PORT"'; sleep 10; done >/dev/null 2>&1' &
```

Probably I made a mistake with quotation marks.
Thank you all for you help

(especially Kamil Cuk for the solution)

Comment: Be sure to redirect `nohup` output to null too, otherwise you'll get those `nohup.out` files spawning. So `nohup sh -c .... >/dev/null 2>&1`